# connecting qlikview to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, connection, odbc, qlikview

I am trying to connect qlikview to my tables in phpmyadmin. I have tried several different ODBC drivers but I am always unable to connect. If this is possible can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to get help you have to provide more information. Reading the SO FAQ will help you! First of all you should describe in detail what you tried to solve your problem. By the way I think you only have an odbc problem (not related to QlikView). So maybe you change the title of the question.

Comment: It should definitely be possible.  Any database with ODBC drivers should be aaccessible to Qlikview.  Your MySQL database is no different.  Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) and see if this driver works if you haven't already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and solved it just by using the 32bit version (by forcing 32 bit).